# Where is my mistake in calculating the variance of 4 values?

Tags: c++

I get the correct output for mean, but I do not get the correct output for variance. Sample input is 8, 10, 12, 14.

It should output the mean as 11, and variance as 5. However, I get the mean is 11, and variance is 6.66667.

```
// Include statements
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

// Main function
int main ()
{
  // Input values
  float n1, n2, n3, n4;
  cout << "Enter four numbers:\n";
  cin >> n1 >> n2 >> n3 >> n4;

  // Calculate mean of 4 values
  float mean;
  mean = (n1+n2+n3+n4)/4;

  // Calculate variance of 4 values
  float variance;
  float var1 = ((n1-mean)*(n1-mean));
  float var2 = ((n2-mean)*(n2-mean));
  float var3 = ((n3-mean)*(n3-mean));
  float var4 = ((n4-mean)*(n4-mean));

  variance = (var1+var2+var3+var4)/3;


  // Print the output
  cout << "mean = " << mean << endl;
  cout << "variance = " << variance << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say that your input is 3 numbers (8, 10 and 12) but your code takes 4 numbers.

Comment: How do you get 8, 10 and 12 to give you a mean of 11?

Comment: standard deviation requires dividing by one less. But variance is divided by n.

Comment: my mistake, I just edited my post, there is indeed 4 inputs, I just accidentally left 1 out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've divided `var1+var2+var3+var4` by 3 rather than 4.

Comment: This might be intended depending on if this is sample or population variance. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17890/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-n-1-in-calculating-population-variance

Comment: I looked up the formula for variance and it said to divide by n-1, I didn't realize there are two different types of variance. @frslm

Comment: Scohe001 is right.

Comment: @user2803082 If you must use the "n-1" formula, then why do you expect your variance to be 5, as mentioned in your question?

Comment: @frslm I think the point is he was supposed to use one variance equation but mistakenly used the wrong one.

Comment: Thank you @scohe001 I didn't think about how there is two different types of variance.

Comment: @user2803082 taking another look at the link I gave, it's actually not a very good explanation (or what I was thinking). [This](http://www.macroption.com/population-sample-variance-standard-deviation/) is a far more explanatory link with both formulas.